# Adobe AIR weird UI bug

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, mxml

I got a bug report for an application that is used by more then 100 people for over an year,
The UI gets weird in this user case, on a Mac OSX using latest Adobe AIR

Here is a section of the UI code, the entire code uses relative layouts with HGroups and VGroups and spacers, no absolute possitions

```
<s:Panel width="100%"  title="Print and Digital">
                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" paddingBottom="6" paddingLeft="6"
                                              paddingRight="6" paddingTop="6"/>
                        </s:layout>
                        <dialogs:HorizConversiopnsComponent width="100%" id="conversionsComponent"/>
                        <s:HGroup id="paperSizesResGroup" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">

                            <s:ComboBox id="DIN_combobox" width="33%" change="paperSizeHandler(event)"/>
                            <s:ComboBox id="ANSI_combobox" width="33%" change="paperSizeHandler(event)"/>
                            <s:ComboBox width="33%" id="units_combobox" change="updateInterface()"/>
                        </s:HGroup>

                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label width="50" paddingLeft="0" text="Width:"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="width_input" width="80" height="22"
                                                      valueChanged="docDimEdited(event)"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label width="50" paddingLeft="0" text="Height:"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="height_input" width="80" height="22"
                                                      valueChanged="docDimEdited(event)"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label id="leadingLabel" paddingLeft="0" text="Leading (pt):"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="leading_input" width="80" height="22"
                                                      valueChanged="docDimEdited(event)"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label id="correctLeadingLabel" paddingLeft="0" text="Applied Leading (pt):"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="correctLeading_input" width="80" 
                                                      contentBackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" editable="false"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label id="charHeightLabel" paddingLeft="0" text="Character Height (pt):"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="characterHeight_input" width="80"
                                                      height="22"
                                                      valueChanged="docDimEdited(event)"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label width="90" text="1st Image-line:"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="firstImg_input" width="80" contentBackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" editable="false"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label id="hOffsetLabel" text="Horizontal Width (pt):"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="horizOffset_input" width="80" 
                                                      contentBackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" editable="false"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label id="docImgLinesLabel" text="Document lines:"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="docLines_input" width="80" editable="false" textMode="true"/>
                        </s:HGroup>

                        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="25" gap="6" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label width="72" text="Proportions:"/>
                            <s:RadioButton label="Width" id="widthProp_radio" selected="true" groupName="prop_radiogroup" />
                            <s:RadioButton label="Height" id="heightProp_radio" groupName="prop_radiogroup"/>
                            <s:Spacer width="100%" height="10"/>
                            <dialogs:NumericTextInput id="proportionInput" width="80" height="22"
                                                      keyDown="updateProportionsClicked(event)"
                                                      />
                        </s:HGroup>

                    </s:Panel>
```

Here is how it looks like (check the HGroup with the label 1st image ... or the Proportions HGroup
[image]

And here is how the application looks in a normal case

[image]

The user says that the screen is not a retina display so I have no idea what is wrong on this case, the user uninstalled and reinstalled the application and installed latest Adobe AIR.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  The code and screenshots are good; but I think you need an expanded description of what is wrong w/ the first one but right in the second one.  Unfortunately "check the HGroup with the label 1st image ... or the Proportions HGroup" does not communicate anything to me.  It is not obvious to me why the first screen is wrong; but the second one is right.

Comment: Things start to go wrong at "1st Image-line". The only difference I can see with the other components is that the Label has a fixed width of `90`; all the other Labels have a relative width of `100%`.

Comment: Are you using embedded fonts? They seem to be slightly different in both screenshots. My bet's on a font issue anyway.

Comment: The problem is not in the displayed code.

Comment: @RlAstar You are right, for some reason the user application does not use Arial, I will wait a response to see if somehow Arial is missing. Thanks.